# How do we know that $\sin(\pi/12)$ is equivalent to $\sin(\pi/3)\cos(\pi/4)-\cos(\pi/3)\sin(\pi/4)$? Are there any rules/laws that prove it as such?

Tags: trigonometry

I've been learning trigonometry identities, but I am having some trouble understanding them. How do we know that $\sin(\pi/12)$ is equivalent to $\sin(\pi/3)\cos(\pi/4)-\cos(\pi/3)\sin(\pi/4)$? Are there any rules/laws that prove it as such? Any input regarding this would be much appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: What does it mean to say that two numbers are equivalent?

Comment: Does $\pi/12=\pi/3-\pi/4$ ring any bell?

Comment: [Angle difference identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there exists a relatively well-known identity, as follows:

$$\sin(α-β)=\sin(α)*\cos(β)-\cos(α)*\sin(β)$$

In your example, we can see that $α = \frac{\pi}{3}$, and $β = \frac{\pi}{4} $.

As we can see, $α-β$ becomes $\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4} \implies \frac{\pi}{12}$.

So,

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{12})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})*\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})-\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})*\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$$

Comment: Correct, but please don't rush to post answers like this when just a hint is all the OP should get.

Comment: Sorry!  This is my first post on here, so I'm not aware of the culture.  Should I revise?

Comment: Leave it now. Watch for a while and learn the culture, then resume answering to help people.

Comment: @Kafkaesque: You will see some questions on here that people are looking for answers to avoid doing any work ("solve it for me") or are doing it under time constraints (math Olympiads) so giving out the answer should be directly proportional to the answer you give; that is, the more information the poster has, the more information you should give. 

tl;dr - less effort, hints; more effort, more extensive answer.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you!